# Is there a faster way to mask an array?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a numpy array and I need to mask it.
My function looks like this:

```
def mask_arr(arr, min, max):
    for i in range(arr.size-1):
        if arr[i] < min:
            arr[i] = 0
        elif arr[i] > max:
            arr[i] = 1
        else:
            arr[i] = 10
```

Problem is the array is huge and it takes a long time to mask it.
How can i achieve the same result but faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use nested `np.where` like the following:

```
import numpy as np
q = np.random.rand(4,4)
# array([[0.86305369, 0.88477713, 0.58776518, 0.69122533],
#   [0.52591559, 0.33155238, 0.50139987, 0.66812239],
#   [0.83240284, 0.70147098, 0.17118681, 0.59652636],
#   [0.82031661, 0.32032657, 0.55088698, 0.28931661]])
np.where(q > 0.8, 1, np.where(q < 0.3, 0, 10))
# array([[ 1,  1, 10, 10],
#   [10, 10, 10, 10],
#   [ 1, 10,  0, 10],
#   [ 1, 10, 10,  0]])
```

## Edit:

Based on your question, In the case you want to change the value in the case the element of the array is not greater then `maxVal` or smaller then `minVal` you can do or any other logic that you want:

```
import numpy as np
q = q = np.random.rand(4,4)
minVal = 0.3
maxVal = 0.9
qq = np.where(q > 0.8, 1, np.where(q < 0.3, 0, 2 * q))
```

Where `q` is:

```
[[0.63604995 0.18637738 0.90680287 0.64617278]
 [0.97435344 0.04670638 0.3510053  0.71613776]
 [0.17973416 0.50296747 0.35085383 0.853201  ]
 [0.27820978 0.69438172 0.96186074 0.96625938]]
```

And `qq` is:

```
[[1.27209991 0.         1.         1.29234556]
 [1.         0.         0.7020106  1.43227553]
 [0.         1.00593493 0.70170767 1.        ]
 [0.         1.38876345 1.         1.        ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

You could use three simple assignments based on your rules. This uses the native vectorization available in `numpy` and hence will be quite faster compared to what you have tried.

```py
# minval, maxval = 0.3, 0.8
condition = np.logical_and(a>=minval, a<=maxval)
a[a<minval] = 0 
a[a>maxval] = 1
a[condition] = 10 # if a constant value of 10
a[condition] *= 2 # if each element gets multiplied by 2
```

**Output**:

```sh
[[10.  0. 10.  1.  0.]
 [10. 10. 10.  0. 10.]
 [ 1. 10. 10.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1. 10. 10.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 10. 10. 10.]]
```

### Dummy Data

```py
a = np.random.rand(5,5)
```

**Output**:

```sh
array([[0.68554168, 0.27430639, 0.4382025 , 0.97162651, 0.16740865],
       [0.32530579, 0.3415287 , 0.45920916, 0.09422211, 0.75247522],
       [0.91621921, 0.65845783, 0.38678723, 0.83644281, 0.95865701],
       [0.26290637, 0.83810284, 0.55327399, 0.3406887 , 0.26173914],
       [0.24974815, 0.08543414, 0.78509214, 0.64663201, 0.61502744]])
```

### Convenience Function

Since you mentioned that you could also self-multiply the target elements by a factor of two, I extended that functionality to either absolute assignment (setting a value of 10) or relative update (add, subtract, multiply, divide) w.r.t the current values of the array.

```py
def mask_arr(arr, 
             minval: float = 0.3, 
             maxval: float = 0.8, 
             update_type: str = 'abs', 
             update_value: float = 10, 
             rel_update_method: str = '*', 
             mask_floor: float = 0.0, 
             mesk_ceiling: float = 1.0):
    """Returns the array arr after setting lower-bound (mask_floor), 
    upper-bound (mask_ceiling), and logic-for-in-between-values. 

    """
    # minval, maxval = 0.3, 0.8
    condition = np.logical_and(arr>=minval, arr<=maxval)
    arr[arr<minval] = lowerbound 
    arr[arr>maxval] = upperbound
    if update_type=='abs':
        # absolute update 
        arr[condition] = update_value
    if update_type=='rel': 
        # relative update
        if rel_update_method=='+':
            arr[condition] += update_value
        if rel_update_method=='-':
            arr[condition] -= update_value
        if rel_update_method=='*':
            arr[condition] *= update_value
        if rel_update_method=='/':
            arr[condition] /= update_value
    return arr
```

#### Example

```py
# declare all inputs
arr = mask_arr(arr, 
                minval = 0.3, 
                maxval = 0.8, 
                update_type = 'rel', 
                update_value = 2.0, 
                rel_update_method = '*', 
                mask_floor = 0.0, 
                mesk_ceiling = 1.0)

# using defaults for 
#   mask_floor = 0.0, 
#   mesk_ceiling = 1.0
arr = mask_arr(arr, 
                minval = 0.3, 
                maxval = 0.8, 
                update_type = 'rel', 
                update_value = 2.0, 
                rel_update_method = '*')

# using defaults as before and 
# setting a fixed value of 10
arr = mask_arr(arr, 
                minval = 0.3, 
                maxval = 0.8, 
                update_type = 'abs', 
                update_value = 10.0)
```

Comment: if instead of 10, i want to put 2*arr[i]

Comment: adding the logic for arr[i]*2

Answer (score 1):

With numpy you don't need to do loops for such operations.
More, I would recommend you not using 'min' and 'max' as variable names given they are reserved names.

Try the following

```
arr[arr < min_val]=0
arr[arr > max_val]=1
arr[(arr<=max_val) & (arr>=min_val)]=10
```